# c# : gridpanel with url in each row to download files

Tags: c#, ext.net

This is my grid in code behind:

```
GridPanel grid = new GridPanel
{
    Height = 200,
    EnableColumnHide = false,
    EmptyText = "No Documents",
    Store =
    {
        new Store
        {
            Model = 
            {
                new Model 
                {
                    Fields = { new ModelField("Name") }
                }
            },
            DataSource = data
        }
    },
    ColumnModel =
    {
        Columns =
        {
            new Column { ID = "clmDoc", Text = "Documents Exported", DataIndex = "Name", Width = 400  }
        }
    }
};
```

How I can show a url to the file in each row so the user can download the file? Files are stored in `~/Files/Export/Documents/file1.pdf` etc

Comment: is this ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @mahlatse nope, web forms

Answer (score 0):

Declare your column like this:

```
new Column()
        {                    
            Text = "MyColumn",
            DataIndex = "UrlField",
            Width = 200,
            Renderer = new Renderer("function (value, metadata, record) { return '<a href=\"http://www.mylink.com\" target=top >'+value+'<a/>'} ")

        }
```